# Granger causality test for integrated time series

Tags: cointegration, unit-root, stationarity, granger-causality

I have two time series that are both non-stationary at level. The ADF test says they have a unit root. When taking the first difference of each time series, they are now stationary. I guess this is denoted as "I(1)".

Now I test for cointegration (Engle-Granger two-step method) of the time series and apply the Granger causality test as provided in [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests.html).

**Questions:**

1. Do I apply the cointegration test on the first-difference values? Do I test with the AIC-selected maxlag or without?
2. When I see that the first-difference time series are cointegrated (both have $p<0.05$), then can I simply apply the statsmodels Granger causality test?

Comment: Check out the excellent [Dave Giles blog](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/) posts on Granger causality, cointegration and especially on *Granger causality in case of cointegration* [here](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2014/05/questions-about-granger-causality.html) and explore the links to other related blog posts in the first paragraph, and [here](http://davegiles.blogspot.ca/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html).

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: no, you apply the cointegration test on the original series (that you believe to be non-stationnary I(1) ). Regarding selection of lag, one would usually base the choice on a criterion like AIC indeed.

Question 2: again, you would run the cointegration test on the original series. Note that Granger causality does not imply/require cointegration: 2 series can have Granger causality among themselves if they are both I(0), both I(1), or cointegrated.

Comment: You say *Granger causality is independent of cointegration*. Not quite. Dave Giles notes in his popular blog post ["Testing for Granger Causality"](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html): *If two or more time-series are cointegrated, then there must be Granger causality between them - either one-way or in both directions. However, the converse is not true. So, if your data are cointegrated but you don't find any evidence of causality, you have a conflict in your results.* See the post for details.

Comment: Fair point, thanks for pointing this out! I've changed from "is independent of cointegration" to "does not imply cointegration"

Comment: When only one series has a unit root, do I still compute the first difference of both series or only for the one with the unit root?